# The relation between energy quanta of an Einstein solid and the equipartition value of heat capacity

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics

Consider an Einstein solid with quantized energy values $U=q\epsilon$ and $N$ oscillators. I calculated some values of an Einstein solid numerically through a function in R (at the bottom of the post). In an exercise I'm supposed to estimate $\epsilon$.

Apparently the answer is that I can estimate it by showing that $kT/\epsilon$ is approximately $1/3$ when the heat capacity reaches half of its maximum value (this value is called the equipartition value). I find this conclusion really confusing, since the energy quanta don't have anything to do with the heat capacity (or do they?). The **exact** wording in the solution of the exercise is

> Note that in the high-temperature limit the heat capacity approaches the result predicted by the equipartition theorem, $C=Nk$ (since there are two degrees of freedom per oscillator). Below $kT=\epsilon$. however, the heat capacity falls off dramatically. (...) The value of $\epsilon$ can be estimated by noting that the heat capacity reaches half of its equipartition value at $kT\approx\epsilon/3$.

Could anyone please explain how does conclusion works? I can't get a grasp on understanding the relation between the energy quanta and the equipartition value of heat capacity.

The function I wrote to produce a table uses column names such as `C_Nk` where I in fact mean $C/Nk$, R just doesn't handle slashes in function names so well:

```
install.packages('gmp');install.packages('Rmpfr');library('gmp');library('Rmpfr')
EinsteinProperties <- function(N){
     q_total=100
     q=0:q_total
     Omega=formatMpfr(chooseMpfr(N+q-1,q),digits=2)
     S_k=formatMpfr(log(chooseMpfr(N+q-1,q)),digits=4)
     kT_eps=rep(0,length(q))
     C_Nk=rep(0,length(q))
     for(i in 0:q_total){
         if(i>0&&i<q_total){
             kT_eps[i+1]=formatMpfr(2/(log(chooseMpfr(N+(i+1)-1,i+1))-log(chooseMpfr(N+(i-1)-1,i-1))),digits=2)
         }else if(i==0||i==q_total){
             kT_eps[i+1]=0
         }
     }
     for(i in (0:q_total)){
         if(i==1){
             C_Nk[i+1]=formatMpfr(2/(2/(log(chooseMpfr(N+(i+2)-1,i+2))-log(chooseMpfr(N+(i)-1,i))))/N,digits=2)
         } else if(i>1&&i<q_total){
             C_Nk[i+1]=formatMpfr(2/(2/(log(chooseMpfr(N+(i+2)-1,i+2))-log(chooseMpfr(N+(i)-1,i)))-2/(log(chooseMpfr(N+(i)-1,i))-log(chooseMpfr(N+(i-2)-1,i-2))))/N,digits=2)
         } else {
            C_Nk[i+1]=0
         }
     }
     table <- cbind(q,Omega,S_k,kT_eps,C_Nk)
     layout(matrix(1:2,1,2))
     graph_S_k <- plot(q,S_k,type="l",xlab="U/eps",ylab="S/k",main="Entropy",xlim=c(0,100))
     graph_C_Nk <- plot(kT_eps[2:q_total],C_Nk[2:q_total],type="l",xlab="kT/eps",ylab="C/Nk",main="Heat capacity",xlim=c(0,2),ylim=c(0,1))
     return(table)
}
EinsteinProperties(50)
```

Comment: What programming language *does* handle slashes in variables?

Comment: @KyleKanos LaTeX if you want it to ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The heat capacity of an Einstein solid is given by
\begin{equation}
C = Nk \left(\frac{\epsilon}{kT}\right)^{2} \frac{e^{\epsilon/kT}}{(e^{\epsilon/kT}-1)^{2}},
\end{equation}
where $N$ is the number of degrees of freedom. So the value of the energy quantum $\epsilon$, or more precisely the ratio $x\equiv\epsilon/kT$ matters! The above equation tends to the equipartition value $Nk$ as $x \rightarrow 0$, and the half maximum corresponds the value of $x$ satisfying
\begin{equation}
x^{2}\frac{e^{x}}{(e^{x}-1)^{2}} =\frac{1}{2}.
\end{equation}
It turns out that the solution is $x_{\rm{half}} = 2.98287\ldots \approx 3$, and this is the origin of the relation $kT/\epsilon\approx 1/3$ given to you.

Comment: I've asked a followup question since the next problem derives the same formula (so I reckon I can't use it now): http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/133077/followup-to-the-relation-between-energy-quanta-of-an-einstein-solid-and-the-equ?lq=1 - Anyway, I'm still not getting why it should be half and not say, three quarter, or a quarter etc. The chosen value of $C$ just seems baseless to me.